# Extensibilidade V10 erro evento DepoisDeAbrirEmpresa ao abrir CustomForm

Tags: c#

Com a ultima atualização do PRIMAVERA este código Demo que estava a funcionar anteriormente, no evento abrir empresa, deixou de funcionar.

```
using (var result = BSO.Extensibility.CreateCustomFormInstance(typeof(FDU_GuiaEntrada)))
{
    if (result.IsSuccess())
    {
        (result.Result as FDU_GuiaEntrada).Show();
    }
}
```

Erro:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Existe outra forma de mostrar um `CustomForm` ?

Comment: A ideia é chamar o formulário sem ser via código?

Comment: Olá Rui, não vai funcionar essa tentativa de abrir um form nesse evento, a shell do erp ainda não foi totalmente carregada para suportar o form. Qual a finalidade de abrir um form nesse evento?

Comment: Existem, pelo menos, duas formas de abrir um customform: (1) Usando esse mesmo código a ser executado pela chamada de uma função de utilizador do tipo "Macro Extensibilidade"; (2) Criando uma função de utilizador do tipo "Formulário do Utilizador". Ambas as funções podem depois ser colocadas num menu do utilizador.

Comment: Existe a necessidade de abrir um form de utilizador ao abrir empresa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde

Pelo que consegui apurar trata-se de é um erro da ultima publicação do ERP PRIMAVERA e deve ser disponibilizada correcção.